# question on showing convergence of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

$Let$  $\mu$ be a positive Borel measure and  for n=1,2, \cdots, let $\{g_n\}$ be a sequence of polynomial of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$. also,$g_n(i)=1$

Question: I am currently doing a calculation and I am stuck with this integral.

I need to justify that integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g_n(x) (x-i)|^2 d \mu(x) < \infty $$ for all $n$.

Here $i$ is a complex number.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $g_n$ the same as $p_n$?  If not, what is $g_n$?

Comment: Yes, I will fix the typo right away

Comment: you have the degree equal to the sequence index?

Comment: Why would you think that integral is finite? There are simple counterexamples.

Comment: @zhw. Yes, the degree is equal to the sequence index.

Comment: The right way to say that is: For $n=1,2,\dots$ let $g_n$ be a polynomial of degree $n.$

Comment: @zhw. I forgot to add the extra condition that $g_n(i) =1$.  Is it still going to be finite if $g_n(i) =1$. Also is there any particular case in which it can converge?

Comment: What is $i?$$\,\,$

Comment: $i =\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: If $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, then that integral is never finite, unless $g_n\equiv 0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Lebesgue measure, we have the following:

Note that $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} |p(x)| = \infty$ for any non-constant polynomial.  But then there exist some $M,R > 0$ such that $|p(x)| > M$ whenever $|x| > R$.  It then follows that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |p(x)| > \int_{[-1,1]} |p(x)| + \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus [-1,1]} M = \infty.$$
On the other hand, if $p(x) = C$, then
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |p(x)| = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |C| = \begin{cases} \infty & \text{if $C\ne 0$, and} \\ 0 & \text{if $C=0$.} \\ \end{cases} $$
Therefore the integral of a polynomial is finite if and only if that polynomial is the zero polynomial.  By hypothesis, $(g_n(x)(x-i))^2$ is a polynomial of degree $2n+1$, thus it cannot be the zero polynomial, therefore the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |g_n(x)(x-i)|^2
$$ diverges for all $n$.

---

On the other hand, if $\mu$ is a finite measure supported on some compact set, then the finiteness of the integral follows fairly easily from the fact that continuous functions are bounded on compact sets.  On the third hand, one can imagine finite measures that don't "decay fast enough" to crush a polynomial of high degree (I'm thinking of a Lebesgue-Stiltjes measure corresponding to something like $|x|^{-2}$), so just assuming that $\mu$ is a finite measure is not going to be good enough.

Basically, without knowing more about your measure, that is probably the best that we can do.

Comment: The integral is over $\mathbb R$ not $ \mathbb C.$

Comment: @zhw Indeed.  I missed that.  Thank you.  On the bright side, it doesn't change the result.